# How do I export/import data from my inventory program?

Tags: python

I have an inventory program. The data is entered into two lists then added to a list called inventory. I have never created a program that saves an output of data to be used/edited at a later time. Here is what I have:

Program entitled: Clean copy.py

```
import os

class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.item = []
        self.qty = []

    def remove(self, name):
        ix = self.item.index(name)
        self.item.pop(ix)
        self.qty.pop(ix)

    def add(self, name, qty):
        self.item.append(name)
        self.qty.append(qty)

    def update(self, name, update):
        if update >= 0:
            self.qty[self.item.index(name)] += update
        elif update <= -1:
            self.qty[self.item.index(name)] += update

    def search(self, name):
        pos = self.item.index(name) if name in self.item else -1
        if pos >= 0:
            return self.item[pos], self.qty[pos]
        else:
            return None

    def __str__(self):
        out = ""
        zipo = list(zip(self.item, self.qty))
        for foobar in zipo:
            out += f"Item : {foobar[0]} \nQuantity : {foobar[1]}\n"
            out += "----------\n"
        return out


def menuDisplay():
    """Display the menu"""
    print('=============================')
    print('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print('=============================')
    print('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print('(3) Update Inventory')
    print('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print('(99) Quit')


def add_one_item(inventory):
    print('Adding Inventory')
    print('================')
    while True:
        try:
            new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
            assert new_name.isalpha(), "Only letters are allowed!"
            new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
            inventory.add(new_name, new_qty)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()


def remove_one_item(inventory):
    print('Removing Inventory')
    print('==================')
    removing = input('Enter the item name to remove from inventory: ')
    inventory.remove(removing)


def ask_exit_or_continue():
    return int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))


def update_inventory(inventory):
    print('Updating Inventory')
    print('==================')
    item = input('Enter the item to update: ')
    update = int(input(
        "Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
    inventory.update(item, update)


def search_inventory(inventory):
    print('Searching Inventory')
    print('===================')
    search = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
    result = inventory.search(search)
    if result is None:
        print("Item not in inventory")
    else:
        name, qty = result
        print('Item:     ', name)
        print('Quantity: ', qty)
        print('----------')


def print_inventory(inventory):
    print('Current Inventory')
    print('=================')
    print(inventory)


def main():
    inventory = Inventory()
    while True:
        try:
            menuDisplay()
            CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
            if CHOICE in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
                if CHOICE == 1:
                    add_one_item(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 2:
                    remove_one_item(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 3:
                    update_inventory(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 4:
                    search_inventory(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 5:
                    print_inventory(inventory)
                exit_choice = ask_exit_or_continue()
                if exit_choice == 99:
                    exit()
            elif CHOICE == 99:
                exit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again!"+str(e))
            print()

        # If the user pick an invalid choice,
        # the program will come to here and
        # then loop back.


main()
```

Then I made a blank TextEdit document entitled Inventory.

Lastly, I made another python project entitled: Controller.py

Code:

```
import socket, os

os.system('cls')

file = open('Clean copy.txt', 'r')

inventory_list = []


for x in file.readlines():
    inventory_list.append(x.rstrip())

report = open('Inventory', 'a')

for y in item_list:
    report.write("-" * 45 + '/n')
    report.write(y + '\t->\t' + socket.gethostbyname(y))

report.close()
```

So to recap I am trying to take the data that is inputed into this program (Clean copy.py) and save it to a document (Inventory) so it can be load/read/edited at a later time.

Please help I have never saved data that has been inputed. The last time I asked a question over this I got a lot of negative marks and did not get any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pickle, a serialization tool that can serialize the data into a byte file.
[https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#:~:text=%E2%80%9CPickling%E2%80%9D%20is%20the%20process%20whereby,back%20into%20an%20object%20hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CPickling%E2%80%9D%20is%20the%20process%20whereby,back%20into%20an%20object%20hierarchy).

To save a file, you can pickle it. To decode a file to use it, you can unpickle it.